# What perl regular expression will correctly match a javascript associative array?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, perl

I've got some Javascript code that I need to parse with Perl:

```
var materials ={
    foo: "bar",
    bar: "baz",
    baz: "foo"
},
```

I've got this Javascript variable as a string, and I want to match the associative array's body so that I can parse it as JSON with Perl using `parse_json()`.  I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong with my regular expression:

`my ($json_str) = $js_code =~ m/var\smaterials\s=\s+({.+}),/i;`

`$json_str` ends up being uninitialized.

Comment: You might just look at it differently. Right now you are trying to match the json portion of the string.  Fixing your regex would be trivial (allow `\s*` instead of requiring `\s+`). However, JSON can be more complex than this example.  It might be easier to just drop the portion you do not want: `s/^[^{]+//`.  This will strip everything that comes before the first `{`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, though? `JSON.stringify(materials)` will give you real JSON to start with, which makes everything a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an exclude group like `[^}]+` works as expected also if there are multiple elements:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $js_code = <<'__END__';
var previousOne =  {
    pFoo: "pBar",
    pBar: "pBaz",
    pBaz: "pFoo"
},
var materials ={
    foo: "bar",
    bar: "baz",
    baz: "foo"
},
var anotherOne = {
   aFoo: "aBar",
   aBar: "aBaz",
   aBaz: "aFoo"
}
__END__

my ($json_str) = $js_code =~ m/\s*var\s+materials\s*=\s*({[^}]+}),?/;
print "json_str = ${json_str}\n";
```

I've relaxed some whitespace constraints. You can test it and edit it online [here](http://ideone.com/6yOsGx)

Comment: Why downvote? It's a genuine question. I've tested it (and everyone can do the same executing the perl script in the answer...)

Comment: Thank you for point me in the right direction: i've collapsed the default greedy with backtrack behaviour with the greedy *possessive* behaviour (as ``[\s\S]++``) that not backtrack at all. I've removed the wrong assumption but leave the code cause it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
my ($json_str) = $js_code =~ m/var\smaterials\s=\s*({[\s\S]+?}),/i;

                                                      ^^^^
```

The problem is `.` does not match `\n` by default.So either use `[\s\S]` or use `(?s)` the `DOTALL` flag.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/7

or

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/8

Comment: Why ``[\s\S]+`` doesn't match ``'}'`` also? (and all the rest till the end of the string) Doesn't it need the lazy modifier ``'?'`` to work? Like this ``[\s\S]+?``

Comment: @GsusRecovery that's d same problem with ur answer.Ur assumption is wrong.it will match `}` but then it will backtrack as re has to match a `}` as well.To `[\s\S]` will backtrack leaving `}` for `}` to match.Same with `,` as well.`?` is needed only if there are multiple `}` as then it will match till last `}`

Answer (score 2):

If you can quote the JSON object's keys (like the example below), you could try [JSON::Decode::Regexp](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::Decode::Regexp), the module includes a regex you can use to match a JSON. As a bonus, you get the JSON object loaded as Perl hash. Example code:

```
use Data::Dump;
use JSON::Decode::Regexp;

my $json_code = <<'_';
var materials ={
    "foo": "bar",
    "bar": "baz",
    "baz": "foo"
},
_

if ($json_code =~ /(\{.+)/s) {
    local $_ = $1;
    local $^R;
    eval { /\A$JSON::Decode::Regexp::FROM_JSON/ } or die "No match";
    die "No match: $@" if $@;
    print "Match: "; dd $_;
}
```

will print:

```
Match: { bar => "baz", baz => "foo", foo => "bar" }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no spaces between the equal sign and the curly bracket, but the pattern requires at least one. Remove the `\s+` or change it to `\s*`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @WesFoster How is this not an answer? It is an attempt to solve the problem, and as far as I can tell a correct one. Could you please elaborate on your reasoning here?